# Cascading Combo Boxes Within a Sub Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a cascading combo box within a subform. I modified the row source for the second combo box based on criteria from the initial combo box as such

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![SubFormName]![Combo1Name] & "*"
```

I then added this to the after update event of the first combo box

```
Me.Combo2Name = vbNullString
Me.Combo2Name.Requery
```

This works great if opening only the subform directly. However, when in the parent form it prompts "Enter Parameter Value" if I key it in manually when prompted it works fine.

But I can't seem to have it push the Combo1 values automatically...HELP TYIA!

*UPDATE*
I removed the form qualifier as mentioned below
`Like "*" & [Combo1Name] & "*"`
Works great now!

Comment: Remove the form qualifier, just: `Like "*" & [Combo1Name] & "*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combobox RowSource SQL statement does not require the form qualifier prefix when both controls are on the same form. So simplify the criteria:

`Like "*" & [Combo1Name] & "*"`